# how to filter this array using a predicate?

Tags: nsarray, nspredicate, nsset

I have an object called media_item that has a bunch of properties related to it but one of the properties is a set of countries that are strings. What i want to do is get a set(unique list) of all the availble countires across all of the media items. SO for instance heres an example i have 2 objects. `object1.countries[us,gbr,spa]` and `object2.countries[us,chi,fre]`. What i want to do is create another set of these objects and display them to the user. So the outcome should be `newArray[us,gbr,spa,chi,fre]` I tried using NSPredicate but i cant figure out he format string heres what i thought would work.

```
NSMutableArray *all_media_items = [[[[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_presentations]arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:_videos]arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:_brochures]mutableCopy];
NSSet *all_available_countries_set = [[NSSet setWithArray:all_media_items]filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.countries"]];
```

In this case self would be considered the media object right? and then the dot accessor is saying view all the indexes of the array and place them into the new arrray if they are not duplicates. It looks right but i cant figure it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it without using NSPRedicate like so

```
NSMutableArray *all_media_items = [[[_presentations arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:_brochures]arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:_videos]mutableCopy];
NSMutableSet *all_countries = [NSMutableSet set];
[all_media_items enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UFPMediaObject *media_object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [media_object.countries enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString* country, BOOL *stop) {
        [all_countries addObject:country];
    }];
}];
```

Which is fine and dandy but i wanna know how to do it with NSPRedicate